No internet connection and missing ethernet option after installing driver for second monitor (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS)
I'm encountering an issue with my internet connection and ethernet settings after installing a driver for a second monitor on my (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS)  system
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:
ip link show

result : 1: lo:<LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWEN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00  brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

lspci -nm | grep -i net 

resutl: Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co. Ltd. RTL8125 2.5Gbe Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)

nmcli networking connectivity 

unknowen

Additional Information:
Despite installing the necessary dependencies, including the r8125 and dkms packages, I'm still unable to comprehend the root cause of this issue. My understanding of these commands is limited, as my primary focus has been on finding solutions rather than understanding their underlying mechanics.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this internet connectivity issue and restore the functionality of my Ethernet connection.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Additional Note:
As a newcomer to Ubuntu, I apologize if the question does not provide a clear description of the problem. My understanding of Ubuntu and its inner workings is still developing, and I may not fully grasp the intricacies of what's happening. Any guidance or assistance provided would be immensely appreciated as I navigate through this issue. Thank you for your understanding.
